# JNDI lookup in servlets init method with property load-on-startup

Tags: java, servlets, datasource, jndi

I have a Servlet which initializes its DataSource in the Servlets init method (because it is accessed there the first time). When the servlet is getting loaded I get the following exception message

> Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'

But when the first request is processed the jndi lookup works fine and the DataSource is initialized properly.

Here is my DataSource class:

```
public class PostgresDataSource{

private static DataSource dataSource;

static {
    try {

        dataSource = (DataSource) new InitialContext().lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/somedb");

    } catch (NamingException e) {
        Log.logger.fatal("Failed to initialize DB!");
        Log.logger.error(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static Connection checkOut(){
    if ( dataSource != null )
    {
        try {
            return dataSource.getConnection();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.logger.error("Failed to establish DB connection!");
            Log.logger.error(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Log.logger.error("Failed to check out DB-Connection: Postgres DataSource not initialized!");
        return null;
    }
}

public static void checkIn( Connection dbcon){
    if ( dataSource != null )
    {
        try {
            dbcon.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.logger.error("Failed to close DB connection!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    else
    {
        Log.logger.error("Cannot check in DB-Connection: Postgres DataSource not initialized!");
    }
}
}
```

Anyone encountered the same problem? What's the reason for this and how to solve it?

Comment: Have you called `super.init(config);` method in servlet's init if you are using parametrized init method?

Comment: what app server do you use?

Comment: Servlet's code would help.

Comment: @MaVRoSCy Apache Tomcat 6.0.18

Comment: @Abu No, i haven't. But I tried it right now. Problem still exists.

Comment: @RaviThapliyal The servlet init is not calling the DataSource directly. There is a ModelBuilder in the init which instances a model which calls DAOs which use the DataSource. Hence you can't see anything regarding the DataSource or JNDI lookup in the servlets init method.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using 
dataSource = (DataSource) new InitialContext().lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/somedb");

Please use the following, this may solve the problem

```
        InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
        Context envCtx = (Context) context.lookup("java:comp/env");
        dataSource = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup("jdbc/somedb");
```

Comment: Nope. Same result. But anyway, thanks. What do you think is the problem?

Comment: Where have you defined the DB credentials. I have defined in the context.xml file.

Comment: The credentials are defined in the context.xml. I don't think it's a credential problem because it's working perfect after first request is processed ...

Comment: Looking to the error Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'. When it is instantiating the data source the context is not initialized. Since the code is in static block it may be getting executed before the context is initialized. So just for test can you shift that particular code to the static method checkOut() instead of the static block.

Comment: Did it, but not working. I think you are right concerning the context initialization but i don't get why this is happening. It should be initialized by the container as soon as the init is called!?